# How to add one dictionary value multiple times to an array?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, typeerror, extend

I want to add the value from f1 two times to an array, but the extend() method gives me this error?

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
s = ("f1", "f1")
mo = []
for key, val in shiftweek.items():
    if key in s:
        mo.extend(val)
```

Is there another way to add the value from f1 twice to the array mo?

Best,

Patrick

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your error message doesn't relate to the problem title, and your posted code fails on undefined variables.

Comment: Also, I see no attempt to recognize that `f1` appears twice in `s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `extend` takes an iterable object (list, tuple, etc), but you're passing a single value (int).

You want to use `append` instead.

Here's an example:

```
s = ("f1", "f1")
mo = []
for key, val in shiftweek.items():
    if key in s:
        mo.append(val)
```

**Edit**: if you want to put `n` occurrences of `val` in `mo` where `n` is equal to the number of occurrences of `key` in `s`, then you can do something like this:

```
s = ("f1", "f1")
mo = []
for key, val in shiftweek.items():
     n = s.count(key)
     mo.extend([val] * n)
```

Comment: I tryed append, but then the value for f1 is only one time in the array. I need the array to contain the value of f1 two times, because it is two times in s.

Comment: @Peet oh then you could do `occurrences = s.count(key)` and then `mo.append([val] * count)`

Comment: this was exactly what i needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

.extend() method add a list to your current list, for adding a value, you should use .append() method

I think the code you want is this one

```
s = ("f1", "f1")
mo = []
for key, val in shiftweek.items():
    for i in s:
       if key == i:
           mo.append(val)
```